# How to run DDL commands on SQL Server database from C# and know about its results?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linux

I'm trying to create a database tool (linux, docker, c#, sql server).

I use a `Database.json` file that contains the definition of a database, and try to create a database based on it.

This is a sample script for a table that I create in my program:

```
if not exists (select * from sys.tables where [name] = 'Cultures' and schema_name([schema_id]) = 'languages')
begin
    create table [languages].[Cultures]
    (
        Id bigint not null identity(1,1)
    )
end
```

And I'm using this C# code to run it:

```
public static void Run(string connectionString, string sql)
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (var command = new SqlCommand())
    {
        connection.Open();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = sql;
        var result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Console.WriteLine($"Query:\n{sql}\nResult: {result}");
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that sometimes it creates the table and sometimes it does not.

And the only thing that I have access to is the return value of `ExecuteNonQuery` method which is always `-1` regardless of the success or failure.

So, I'm stuck here.

How can I run DDL commands on SQL Server from C#, and access the result of its execution?

Comment: why try and re-invent DbUp ??? https://dbup.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Use SQL Server Management Studio to connect to database.  In the explorer under Management are the log files that you can look at to see what cause the failure.

Comment: @MitchWheat, that's not what we want. We know that tool. It's similar to EF Core's migration. But we have other requirements too. Thus we had to create a tool for it.

Comment: @jdweng, I'm using Azure Data Studio, not SSMS. I'm on linux.

Comment: A failed "Create Table" should throw something here. So we can just assume that it wasn't executed because of the previous check. You might want to either breakup the script in 2 steps so you can check the result of the initial check in your c# code or log something from your script into the Sql server log and look it up there.

Comment: Or just get rid of the check and just call "Create Table" and work with the Exception thrown in case then.

Comment: @AlirezaHosseinitabar, the `ExecuteNonQuery` result is the number of rows affected by the query. This will be -1 in the case of DDL which does not modify rows. I would expect the table to be created in the context of the database connection with your code if no exception is raised. If you don't see the table in ADS, you might just need to refresh the UI.

Comment: "But we have other requirements too. Thus we had to create a tool for it. " - highly unlikely that DbUp can't do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DDL does not return a rowcount affected, because there aren't any. You need to return something yourself

```sql
if not exists (select 1 from sys.tables where name = 'Cultures' and schema_name([schema_id]) = 'languages')
begin
    create table [languages].[Cultures]
    (
        Id bigint not null identity(1,1)
    );
    select 1;
end
else
    select 0;
```

```cs
public static void Run(string connectionString, string sql)
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
    {
        connection.Open();
        var result = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
        Console.WriteLine($"Query:\n{sql}\nResult: {result}");
    }
}
```